# Mobius image of a line

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been looking at this question;

Let gamma be the mobius transformation defined by:$$\gamma(z) = \frac{2iz-2}{z+1}, z\ne -1$$

Show that $\gamma$ maps the line $\{z: Im z = Re z - 1\}$ into the circle $C(i,1)$.

I've gone about this in a similar method to an example in my notes however I'm not sure if I have the correct answer or not, and if I have I can't really see what I am doing if you understand what I mean.

So I have;

$\gamma(z) \in C(i,1) \Leftrightarrow |\gamma(z)-i|=1$

$\\\Leftrightarrow|\frac{2iz-2}{z+1} -i|=1 \\\Leftrightarrow |iz-2-i|^2=|z+1|^2 \\\Leftrightarrow x^2-2x+y^2+4y+5=x^2+2x+y^2+1 \\\Leftrightarrow x=1$

Writing this out I just have no idea what this is supposed to be... Thanks for any help!

Comment: Let $z = -1+ a (i+1) + b(1-i)$ and show that $a = 0 \implies |y(z)-i| = 1$

Comment: You appear to be attempting to show the transformation in reverse. Aren't you supposed to show the line is transformed into the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to use that these transformations keep clines (they map (circles or lines) into (circles or lines)), then it's enough to check the image of 3 points from the line, as 3 points (the images of the ones you just picked) uniquely determine a cline. Pick easy ones, if you can.

For example -i, 1, 2 + i come to mind.

Their images are, in order: $0, -1 + i, \frac{2i(2+i) - 2 }{3+i} = \frac{4i - 4}{3+i}$.

Check the distance of these points from $i$.

$$|0-i| = 1,\quad |-1 + i - i| = 1,\quad  | \frac{4i - 4 - i(3+i)}{3+i} | = |\frac{3+i}{3+i}| = 1 $$

So as you can see, the image of $3$ points from the line are on the unit circle around $i$. Since the image of the line is a cline, you know that it can only be a circle. And if two circles meet in 3 points, then they are the same.

For the slightly more numbery approach:

$\\...\\\Leftrightarrow|\frac{2iz-2}{z+1} -i|=1 \\\Leftrightarrow |iz-2-i|^2=|z+1|^2$

Up to this point you did well. Now comes the step where you write $\mathbb C \ni z = x + iy$.

Thus $x = \Re (z), y = \Im (z)$. So...

$|i(x+iy) - 2 - i| = | x + iy + 1|$

Then group by real and imaginary parts...

$|(-2 -y) + i(x-1)| = | (x+1) + i y|$

Now realize that these are lengths of vectors...

$(-2-y)^2 + (x-1)^2 = (x+1)^2 + y^2$

Simplify...

$(2+y)^2 - y^2 + (x-1)^2 - (x+1)^2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow 2(2+2y) + (-2)(2x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow (1+y) - x = 0$

And finish up...

$y = x-1 \quad \text{or equivalently } \Im (z) = \Re (z) -1$

Comment: Thank you so much! We haven't seen the notion of clines, however I've heard of them now so I'll be reading!!

Comment: @Killuminati Sure thing, but make sure to do a few more of these calculations by hand. Helps to appreciate the value of the theorems you can use to escape such calculations. :)

Comment: I will be sure to! After all practice definitely does pay off. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Let $$w=\frac{2iz-2}{z+1}\implies z=-\frac{w+2}{w-2i}$$

Now write $z=x+iy$ and $w=u+iv$

Then after a couple of lines of algebra, we get $$x=-\frac{u^2+v^2-2v+2u}{u^2+(v-2)^2}$$ and $$y=\frac{-2u+2v-4}{u^2+(v-2)^2}$$

Now substitute these into the given line equation $y=x-1$ and after some simplification we get $$u^2+(v-1)^2=1$$ which is the circle you are given.

Comment: Thank you! Another interesting way to go about it.